# trying to open in webview a link thats jumps another page

Tags: java, android, webview

yes I searched the site and didn't find something that helps me
because every one are saying use "shouldOverrideUrlLoading"
but that's not helping me - its not working
I am trying to open - In the same page an URL that supposed to open a new page link, but when I press it - nothing happens 
I am using it as a fragment

```
 public class FlightFragment extends Fragment {
    private WebView webView;
    public  FlightFragment(){};
    private String currentUrl;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.flight_fragment,container,false);
        currentUrl = "https://flights.travelor.me/?locale=he";
        webView = (WebView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.flightweb);
        WebViewClient MyWebViewClient= new WebViewClient();
        MyWebViewClient.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(webView, currentUrl);
        ourWebViewClient(currentUrl);
        webView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        webView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new FlightFragment.MyBrowser());
        webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
        webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        webView.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);
        webView.getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
        webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onKey(View view, int i, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
                if (keyEvent.getAction() == keyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    if (webView.canGoBack()) {
                        webView.goBack();
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
        webView.loadUrl(currentUrl);
        return rootView;
    }


    public void ourWebViewClient(String currentUrl) {
        this.currentUrl = currentUrl;
    }

    private class MyBrowser extends WebViewClient {
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")

        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
            if (request.equals(currentUrl)) {
                view.loadUrl(request.getUrl().toString());
            }
            return true;
        }
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            if (url.equals(currentUrl)) {
                view.loadUrl(url);
            }
            return true;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are returning false when your url is intercepted, try changing like this

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            if (url.equals(currentUrl)) {
                Intent intent=new Intent(CurrentActivity.this,NewActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("url to load in NewActivity",url);
                startActivity(intent); //get this url using getextra in new activity
            }

        }
    }});
```

Comment: @golan when your url is intercepted, try to open a new activity with a webview in it

Comment: you mean by intent copy the link on the new web view? I am not sure how to do that - the links that's jumps another page are inside the current page - I am gonna need a listener or something

Comment: just pass the url to load in next activity along with the intent, and get this url in new activity- see updated code

Comment: all good with your code - but - what url?? there are many many links inside the web that jumps it to another page, should I leave it blank?

Comment: which is the url which you have to load on intercept? the same url- pass it to the new activity so that you can load a new webview there

Answer (score 0):

If your target version is >= 26
then override both the function below

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request)

@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
```

Because `shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)` is deprecated since Android N. Write the code for Android N and above in the first override method.

In your code remove this

```
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                if (url.equals(currentUrl)) {
                    return false;
                }
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }
        }});
```

as you are setting your WebViewClient again below this code and change your MyBrowser class

```
    private class MyBrowser extends WebViewClient {
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }

        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
            view.loadUrl(request.getUrl().toString());
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I did what you said - still no effect.. I put the shouldOverrideUrlLoading both inside the TargetApi with the return...

Comment: public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
            if (request.equals(currentUrl)) {
                view.loadUrl(request.getUrl().toString());
            }
            return true;
        }
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            if (url.equals(currentUrl)) {
                view.loadUrl(url);
            }
            return true;

Comment: Update your question with only relevant codes. It's very messy right now. And I can see you are using `setWebViewClient` twice. And remove ` if (url.equals(currentUrl)` condition as when you are clicking on an url link it won't be same as primary link.

Comment: ok I edit my question now as your advice...still not affecting

Comment: not , sorry still no affect.. did exactly like yours - copy past and removed what you said

Answer (score 0):

```
@golan Try to make your Webview fragment as a Activity which will work like a generic view and will open web pages as per requirement based on input url.

shouldOverrideUrlLoading loading method will required if you want to check the input urls.

Do all required web settings like
WebSettings webSettings = webviewBinding.detailWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setDisplayZoomControls(false);
        webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(false);
        webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webSettings.setSupportZoom(true);

Override onBackPressed() method with following code:

if (detailWebView.canGoBack()) {

detailWebView.goBack();

} 
else {
                    super.onBackPressed();
                }

The canGoBack() will allow you to go back upto all web pages and if no more pages to go back it will redirect to you to last loaded activity or view.
```